# Or between groups when one group has to be preceeded by a character

Tags: regex

I have the following data:

```
$200 – $4,500
Points – $2,500
```

I would like to capture the ranges in dollars, or capture the `Points` string if that is the lower range.

For example, if I ran my regex on each of the entries above I would expect:

```
Group 1: 200
Group 2: 4,500
```

and

```
Group 1: Points
Group 2: 2,500
```

For the first group, I can't figure out how to capture only the integer value (without the `$` sign) while allowing for capturing `Points`.

Here is what I tried:

```
(?:\$([0-9,]+)|Points) – \$([0-9,]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/mD9JeR/1

Comment: (?:\$([0-9,]+))|Points – \$([0-9,]+) - Is this what u r looking ? In Group 1 you only want integer value and no string(points). ?

Comment: What regex flavor? If you're certain that it will always be one of those two formats, you may use `\$?([0-9,]+|Points) – \$([0-9,]+)`. If not _and your regex flavor supports Lookahead_, you may use `(?:\$(?=\d))?([0-9,]+|Points) – \$([0-9,]+)`. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQbLIM/1).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed See [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r3ifWw/2). Unfortuantely your regex matches illegal input, also.

Comment: Try this: ((?<=\$)[0-9,]+|Points) – \$([0-9,]+)

Comment: @Booboo I think this will fix it: ((?<=\$)[0-9,]+|(?<!\$)Points) – \$([0-9,]+)

Comment: @marianc But if you put `^` and `$` anchors in your regex to ensure there are no extra characters at the beginning or end of the string, then it will not match '$200 – $4,500' since you cannot have a lookbehind assertion match at the start of the string. What you want is: `((?<=^\$)[0-9,]+|(?<=^)Points) – \$([0-9,]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an alternation here:

```
^(?:(Points)|\$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)) - \$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)$
```

### Demo

The salient points of the above regex pattern are that we use an alternation to match either `Points` or a dollar amount on the lower end of the range, and we use the following regex for matching a dollar amount with commas:

```
\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*
```

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to include the dollar sign in the capture.

Answer (score 1):

Coming up with a regex that doesn't match the `$` is not difficult. Coming up with a regex that doesn't match the `$` and consistently puts the two values, whether they are both numeric or one of them is `Points`, as capture groups 1 and 2 is not straightforward. The difficulties disappear if you use named capture groups. This regex requires the `regex` module from the PyPi repository since it uses the same named groups multiple times.

```
import regex


tests = [
    '$200 – $4,500',
    'Points – $2,500'
]

re = r"""(?x)       # verbose mode
^                   # start of string
(
    \$              # first alternate choice
    (?P<G1>[\d,]+)  # named group G1
  |                 # or
    (?P<G1>Points)  # second alternate choice
)
\x20–\x20           # ' – '
\$
(?P<G2>[\d,]+)      # named group g2
$                   # end of string
"""


# or re = r'^(\$(?P<G1>[\d,]+)|(?P<G1>Points)) – \$(?P<G2>[\d,]+)$'

for test in tests:
    m = regex.match(re, test)
    print(m.group('G1'), m.group('G2'))
```

Prints:

```
200 4,500
Points 2,500
```

**UPDATE**

@marianc was on the right track with his comment but did not ensure that there were no extraneous characters in the input. So, with his useful input:

```
import re


tests = [
    '$200 – $4,500',
    'Points – $2,500',
    'xPoints – $2,500',
]


rex = r'((?<=^\$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|(?<=^)Points) – \$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)$'

for test in tests:
    m = re.search(rex, test)
    if m:
        print(test, '->', m.groups())
    else:
        print(test, '->', 'No match')
```

Prints:

```
$200 – $4,500 -> ('200', '4,500')
Points – $2,500 -> ('Points', '2,500')
xPoints – $2,500 -> No match
```

Note that a `search` rather than a `match` is done since a lookbehind assertion done at the beginning of the line cannot succeed. But we enforce no extraneous characters at the start of the line by including the `^` anchor in our lookbehind assertion.

Answer (score 1):

For the first capturing group, you could use an alternation matching either Points and assert what is on the left is a non whitespace char, or match the digits with an optional decimal value asserting what is on the left is a dollar sign using a positive lookbehind if that is supported.

For the second capturing group, there is no alternative so you can match the dollar sign and capture the digits with an optional decimal value in group 2.

```
((?<=\$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|(?<!\S)Points) – \$(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?<=\$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` Positive lookbehind, assert a `$` to the left and match 1-3 digits and repeat 0+ matching a comma and 3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<!\S)Points` Positive lookbehind, assert a non whitespace char to the left and match Points
- `)` Close group 1
- `–`  Match literally
- `\$` Match `$`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` Match 1-3 digits and 0+ times a comma and 3 digits
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kDYOv0/1)